# viewDidDisappear not showing ad

Tags: swift, startapp, viewdiddisappear

Im using startApp to display ads but when the view disappears it doesn't show the ad. I have `startAppAd = STAStartAppAd()` in `viewDidLoad()` I'm not quite sure what is going wrong.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        startAppAd?.load()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        startAppAd?.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidDisappear` is called when the vc is about to dimiss or popped , so any property is in it's way to deallocate if that vc is not strongly linked , so move the `show` method  also inside `viewDidAppear` or in the ad load finish callback if any